# Output table - Weighted t test

Tags: r, output, summary, weighted

I'm trying to create an output table for several weighted t-tests (calculated using wtd.t.test) for an academic paper, so far with no results. The broom, purrr and stargazer packages do not seem to work with this function.

Do you know how I could get around this?

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to achieve this in `stargazer`, but here's how I would do it in `modelsummary` (disclaimer: I am the author).

As the documentation says, the differences in means will automatically be weighted if your dataset includes a column called "weights". Also note that you can output to a data.frame, or to various other output formats such as HTML, LaTeX, Word, or to one of 4 table-customization packages (`kableExtra`, `gt`, `flextable`, `huxtable`):

```r
library(modelsummary)

dat <- mtcars

dat$weights <- dat$mpg

datasummary_balance(~vs, data = dat)
```

[image]